# Importing Data into Elastic Search from nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am setting up a simple NodeJS REST service to interface with Elasticsearch, using the official JavaScript client. I'm try to import data using nodejs but its failed after 1500 records. i want to import 2 million data in elasticsearch

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far, as well as more info on how it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the idea to import millions of data using nodejs.

1. first of all we need to chunk into lots of parts
2. use async to manage asynchronous behavior of nodejs.
3. By default the memory limit in Node js is 512 mb but in this case you need to increase by  8 gb.

   > node --max-old-space-size=8192 my-node-script.js #increase to 8gb.
4. and now run it.